# Does google glass have any haptic or vibration (physical) feedback function?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm wondering if google glass has any physical feedback capability (haptic or vibration) which most smartphones have. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the device does not have the capability to vibrate or provide haptic feedback. Feedback is audible in the UI.